# Is it a problem that I cannot right-click on "Similar Questions" links?

Tags: bug, status-norepro

If I'm typing up a Question, and SE is trying to encourage me to go see if other ones are similar, then shouldn't SE allow right-clicking on link, without "Leaving this Page" with half-typed question, to see the answer?

Comment: screen shot please? I'm not sure what you're talking about. Also what browser and OS. I can't seem to replicate this.

Comment: Um, it happened yesterday?.   Now on two different OS/browser combos,  I can ONLY see "How to Format" showing up in right panel.  Apologies, will keep trying to replicate, and then screen grab.

Comment: There isn't much point in deleting this kind of thing from meta. Just mark an accepted answer and move on. We've already added the mod tag for marking a bug as norepro, so it's off the dev team's radar.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any issue right clicking on those links in either Firefox or Chrome (on Desktop or mobile). I suspect this is an issue with your browser. You might want to clear your local caches and check if any extentions or site scripts you might have installed have thrown any errors on the console.

Just a note on usability, the links in that section are already targeted to load in a new window, so it is safe to just click on them. Even if they weren't a way to save mouse time in most browsers is to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-Click on links to open them in a new tab.

Comment: I prefer middle click to open in a new tab. (I think most mice with a scroll wheel support using the wheel as a button.) However, middle click might be more of an X Window System tradition (I am using Firefox on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

I totally can right click and open in a new tab. Its just you.